# laravel application moved to another pc

Tags: laravel, configuration

I have just transferred my laravel application to another pc and I have installed composer. I am running composer install at the root of the project but it shows the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"file_put_contents(\/meta\/services.
json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory","file":"C:\\national-fl
eet\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem.php","l
ine":71}}
```

I tried CACLS  -R 755 app/storage (as admin) 
and then composer update but the same error. bootstrap/compiled.php doesn't exists in my project. What should I do?

Comment: @Jason Lewis do you know the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I got this error, because some folders in /app/storage were missing

To fix the error, I manually created the following folders:

```
app/storage/
app/storage/cache/
app/storage/logs/
app/storage/meta/
app/storage/sessions/
app/storage/views/
```

then delete the contents of my vendor folder and run composer update again

Comment: I would also make sure permissions are set to 775, but good call!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `services.json` in `/meta` (or rename it to something else) and try `composer install` again (or `composer update`). It is possible that the file hasn't got the correct rights for Laravel to write to.

Comment: I did it and the same error is displayed. Is it something with php.ini? Because file_put_contents(\/meta\/services.
json) the path is from (\/meta\/services) ?? I just installed wamp

Comment: any other suggestion?